# Typescript, object is possibly undefined inside null check

Tags: typescript, undefined, null-check

Im wondering, how is this code giving `object is possibly undefined error`

```
  if (newFocus) {
    if (viewCache[viewId] !== undefined) {
      dispatch(ViewActions.focusOn(viewCache[viewId].focus));
    } else {
      dispatch(ViewActions.focusOn(newFocus));
    }
  }
```

and line 3 is giving me error, `viewCache[viewId] is possibly undefined` even when wrapped in `if (viewCache[viewId] !== undefined)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to be pointing out that `viewCache` can be `undefined`. You can add a check for its existence too

```
if (newFocus) {
    if (viewCache && viewCache[viewId] !== undefined) {
      dispatch(ViewActions.focusOn(viewCache[viewId].focus));
    } else {
      dispatch(ViewActions.focusOn(newFocus));
    }
  }
```